# How to delete queried results from Splunk database?

Tags: python, splunk-query

Query is on Splunk DB data delete:

My requirement:

I do a query to splunk, based on time stamp, "from date" & "to date".

After I got the list of all events results between the timestamp, I want to delete these list of events from the Splunk database.

Each queried results data will be stored in the destination database, hence I want to delete each queried results data from querying Splunk DB, so that my next query will not end up in giving repetitive results, also I want to free up the storage space in source Splunk DB.

Hence I want a effective solution on how to delete completely the Queried result data, from querying Splunk DB?

Thanks & Regards,
Dharmendra Setty

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can actually delete them to free up storage space.
As written [here](https://answers.splunk.com/answers/1484/how-do-i-delete-events.html), what you can do is simply mask the results from ever showing up again in the next searches.

To do this, simply pipe the "delete" command to your search query.

**BE CAREFUL: First make sure these really are the events you want to delete**

Example:

```
index=<index-name> sourcetype=<sourcetype-name> source=<source-name> 
earliest="%m/%d/%Y:%H:%M:%S" latest="%m/%d/%Y:%H:%M:%S" | delete
```

Where

```
index=<index-name> sourcetype=<sourcetype-name> source=<source-name> 
earliest="%m/%d/%Y:%H:%M:%S" latest="%m/%d/%Y:%H:%M:%S"
```

is the search query